# How can I call reboot() from a PID namespace other than the initial PID namespace, and from the initial PID namespace?

Tags: linux, reboot

The [manpage of reboot()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) says

> **Behavior inside PID namespaces**
>
> Since Linux 3.4, if reboot() is called from **a PID namespace other
>
>   than the initial PID namespace** with one of the cmd values listed
>   below, it performs a "reboot" of that namespace: the "init" process
>   of the PID namespace is immediately terminated, with the effects
>   described in pid_namespaces(7).
>
> The values that can be supplied in cmd when calling reboot() in
>   this    case are as follows:
>
> LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART2
>             The "init" process is terminated, and wait(2) in the parent
>             process reports that the child was killed with a SIGHUP
>             signal.
>
> LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_HALT
>             The "init" process is terminated, and wait(2) in the parent
>             process reports that the child was killed with a SIGINT
>             signal.
>
> For the other cmd values, reboot() returns -1 and errno is set to
>   EINVAL.

I have some limited understanding of PID namespace after reading [its manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html). I was wondering how to call reboot()

- from a PID namespace other  than the initial PID namespace, and
- from  the initial PID namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nsenter to get into other PID namespaces.
To execute reboot from a PID namespace other than the initial PID namespace:

```
/usr/bin/nsenter -p/proc/PID/ns/pid reboot
```

If the target PID is 1:

```
/usr/bin/nsenter -p/proc/1/ns/pid reboot
```

The second question would be the same as simply calling `reboot`, as it would get the current PID context.